# How to prevent Android from relaunching app from launcher

Tags: android

When my app is entered through the launcher, but it is currently in memory it will be restarted at the LauncherActivity instead of resuming in the activity it was in last.

When the user returns to the app through the application switcher however it will retain its state.

How do I make launching from the Launcher have the same behavior as resuming through the application switcher if the application is in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` was set to true and I had forgotten about it.